Solving for a vector field whose divergence is proportional to the field itself
I'm trying to solve the following pair of equations in two dimensions:
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = b E, $$
$$ \nabla \times \mathbf{E} = 0, $$
where $b$ is a real constant, $\mathbf{E} = E\, \hat{\mathbf{s}}$, and $E=E(s)$ in cylindrical coordinates $(s,\phi,z=0)$. It is an electrostatic problem confined to the interior of a circle.
How do I find a solution for this pair of equations including at $s=0$?
The curl equation is automatically solved for $\mathbf{E}=E\,\hat{\mathbf{s}}$. The divergence equation is reduces to
$$ \frac{1}{s} \frac{d}{ds} (sE) = b E. $$
Thus, my question may (?) be rephrased as what are the eigenfuctions of the operator $\frac{1}{s} \frac{d}{ds} (s \cdot)$?
I can find a solution valid at $s>0$. The cylindrical symmetry of the electric field immediately solves the curl equation: the curl of $\mathbf{E} = E(s) \hat{\mathbf{s}}$ is zero indeed. Cylindrical symmetry also facilitates obtaining the solution for the divergence equation at $s>0$. It is
$$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{Ae^{bs}}{s} \hat{\mathbf{s}}, \qquad (s>0) $$
with $A$ some constant. That this is not a solution at $s=0$ is apparent noticing
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} = b \left( \frac{Ae^{bs}}{s} \right) + Ae^{bs} \nabla\cdot \left( \frac{\hat{\mathbf{s}}}{s} \right) = bE + 2\pi sE \delta^2(\mathbf{s}), $$
which equals $bE$ only for $s\neq0$. Alternatively, this is seen by noticing the (two-dimensional) divergence theorem does not hold for $\mathbf{E}$ above, that is, $\int \mathbf{E}\, dV_{2d} \neq \oint \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{S}_{1d}$.

$\mathbf E = E\hat{\mathbf s}$ is not well-defined at $s=0$. The radial coordinate vector field $\hat{\mathbf s}$ makes no sense at the origin. There's no reason the divergence theorem should apply, since the vector field fails to be defined/$C^1$ entirely inside the curve.

Since the electric field is divergence-free and in 2d, you can let $\mathbf{E} = \nabla \phi$ and convert the equation to an eigenvalue problem of Laplacian in the cylindrical geometry.
